# Express 4 use multer as middleware got error

Tags: javascript, express

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router(), 
multer = require('multer');

var uploading = multer({
  dest: __dirname + '../public/uploads/',
})

router.post('/upload', uploading, function(req, res) {
    console.log('uploaded');
})
```

I got an error `Route.post() requires callback functions` error following a photo upload tutorial here. Maybe it's cause by the newer version of expresss? I remember above is the way how we put middle in a route, but why here it doesn't work?

Comment: Check if this error because of other route defined in your application

Answer (score 1):

Basing on the [multer docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer), it seems like you have to use `uploading.single()` or `uploading.array()` as your middleware. This example is obtained from the example usage in the multer docs:

```
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
    // req.file is the `avatar` file 
    // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router(), 
multer = require('multer');

var uploading = multer({
  dest: __dirname + '../public/uploads/',
})
var type = uploading.single('file');

router.post('/upload', type, function(req, res) {
    console.log('uploaded');
})
```